# How to find and replace text in header of landscape page of word document [c# word interop]?

Tags: c#, ms-word, word-interop

I have a template word document and I'm using a function to replace specific text with my desired text. It works for the whole document (main body & headers) except for the header on the last page which is a landscape page.

```
        void FindAndReplace2(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document document, string placeHolder, string newText)
        {

            object missingObject = null;


            object item = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdGoToItem.wdGoToPage;

            object whichItem = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdGoToDirection.wdGoToFirst;
            object replaceAll = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdReplace.wdReplaceAll;
            object forward = true;
            object matchAllWord = true;
            object matchCase = false;
            object originalText = placeHolder;
            object replaceText = newText;

            document.GoTo(ref item, ref whichItem, ref missingObject, ref missingObject);
            foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range rng in document.StoryRanges)
            {
                rng.Find.Execute(ref originalText, ref matchCase,
                ref matchAllWord, ref missingObject, ref missingObject, ref missingObject, ref forward,
                ref missingObject, ref missingObject, ref replaceText, ref replaceAll, ref missingObject,
                ref missingObject, ref missingObject, ref missingObject);
            }
        }
```

I'm not sure why it this function would work on everything but a landscape page. I don't know how to proceed from here.

Main example File

```
            object oMissing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
            object oEndOfDoc = "\\endofdoc"; /* \endofdoc is a predefined bookmark */
            // Start Word and create a new document.
            Word.Application oWord;
            Word.Document oDoc;
            oWord = new Word.Application();
            oWord.Visible = true;
            oDoc = oWord.Documents.Add(ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);


            //Template file
            object oTemplate =  @"FILEPATH";
            oDoc = oWord.Documents.Add(ref oTemplate, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);

            string SiteName="J8865";
            FindAndReplace2(oDoc, "Sample", SiteName);
```

Note: This file is just a excerpt of my main file.

Comment: How many SECTIONS does the document have? There will certainly be one for each change of page orientation... There is no need to use `GoTo` to jump to any page, but looping only the `StoryRanges` is probably not enough. Review the last code sample in this article, paying special attention to `NextStoryRange`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.storyranges

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem in a very different way. I edited my template doc by linking the headers on the portrait page and the landscape page. This is done by selecting the header got to design tab>>Naviagtion>>Next>>Link to previous. Your formatting will probably be messed up. Use "insert alignment tab" to format your header. Useful link. https://cybertext.wordpress.com/2014/07/25/word-auto-aligning-headerfooter-info-in-portrait-and-landscape-pages/.